# My very simple Django Form not passing value to another View

Tags: django, forms

I'm new to Django with a background in Database design.  I spent most of my IT career developing prototypes in MS Access so this Web stuff is new to me.  Now I'm trying to develop prototype reports in Django for a reporting wing of a SAAS offering.  I've got a rough report developed, and if I hard-code the values to pass into some raw queries, it renders a report.  Now I'm trying to make a simple form to enter a value into and pass it into the view that renders the report. (Pardon me if I'm using the correct lingo.)

Here's the form for the data entry: **product_batch.py**

```
from django import forms


class PrdBtchSelect(forms.Form):
    prd_btch_nbr = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Here is the data entry HTML: **prd_btch_select.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Product Batch Select{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<form action={% url 'prd_btch_dtl' form.prd_btch_nbr %} method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Here are the views for the data entry form and for rendering the report: **view\product_batch.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from reports.views import sql
from reports.models import Accounts
from reports.forms import PrdBtchSelect


# import datetime

def prd_btch_dtl(request, prd_btch_nbr):
    """View function for home page of site."""
    acctid = 1
    # prd_btch_nbr = '61210'
    # Generate counts of some of the main objects

    prd_btch_dtl = sql.product_batch_detail(prd_btch_nbr)
    prd_btch_ingr_dtl = sql.product_batch_ingredient_detail(prd_btch_nbr)
    prd_btch_task_dtl = sql.product_batch_task_detail(prd_btch_nbr)
    acct_name = Accounts.objects.get(pk=acctid)

    context = {
        'prd_btch_dtl': prd_btch_dtl,
        'prd_btch_ingr_dtl': prd_btch_ingr_dtl,
        'prd_btch_task_dtl': prd_btch_task_dtl,
        'acct_name': acct_name,
        'report_name': 'Product Batch Detail'
    }

    # Render the HTML template index.html with the data in the context variable
    return render(request, 'reports/prd_btch_ingr_dtl.html', context=context)


def prd_btch_select(request):
    prd_btch_nbr = '000000'
    if request.method == 'post':
        form = PrdBtchSelect(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pass  # does nothing, just trigger the validation
    else:
        form = PrdBtchSelect()

    return render(request, 'reports/prd_btch_select.html', {'form': form})
```

The prd_btch_dtl view gets data from some sql.views.  This part works OK.  You can see where I had it hard coded for my initial testing, which is now commented out.  It is the passing of the **prd_btch_nbr** parameter from **prd_btch_select** to **prd_btch_dtl** that I'm having issues.  The report will render, but it has no data in it.

I googled an answer saying I needed to initialize the prd_btch_nbr which is the line with the '00000', which seems ludicrous, but its there.  It made no difference.

Thanks for any help... If I need to pass/include any other info let me know!

Comment: Hi Coder-1! First of all, please use descriptive names. It is really hard to find bugs when you named your variables like `prd_btch_ingr_dtl`, because our eyes are not able to find the differences at a glance.
Secondly, could you describe in short what you try to achieve? When I get you right, you want to pass a product batch number in a html form and - what should be your output?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  Sorry, I'm kinda old school with my naming conventions.  'prd':'product', 'btch':'batch', 'dtl':'detail', 'nbr': 'number'.  Hope I didn't miss anything.  When I hit submit in the PrdBtchSelect form (Product Batch Select).I want to pass the entered number (which could actually contain any characters) to the prd_btch_dtl (Product Batch Detail) view which collects information from some SQL views and renders a prd_btch_dtl (Product Batch Detail) report.  The user will be able to print this report as needed.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In yours template you direct form to send it to prd_btch_dtl function:

```
<form action={% url 'prd_btch_dtl' form.prd_btch_nbr %} method="post">
```

so in views.py prd_btch_dtl you need to get values from form:

```
def prd_btch_dtl(request, prd_btch_nbr):
"""View function for home page of site."""
acctid = 1
# prd_btch_nbr = '61210'
# Generate counts of some of the main objects

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PrdBtchSelect(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
       prd_btch_nbr = int(form.cleaned_data['prd_btch_nbr'])

prd_btch_dtl = sql.product_batch_detail(prd_btch_nbr)
prd_btch_ingr_dtl = sql.product_batch_ingredient_detail(prd_btch_nbr)
prd_btch_task_dtl = sql.product_batch_task_detail(prd_btch_nbr)
acct_name = Accounts.objects.get(pk=acctid)

context = {
    'prd_btch_dtl': prd_btch_dtl,
    'prd_btch_ingr_dtl': prd_btch_ingr_dtl,
    'prd_btch_task_dtl': prd_btch_task_dtl,
    'acct_name': acct_name,
    'report_name': 'Product Batch Detail'
}

# Render the HTML template index.html with the data in the context variable
return render(request, 'reports/prd_btch_ingr_dtl.html', context=context)
```

you dont need to pass prd_btch_nbr in form action:

```
<form action={% url 'prd_btch_dtl' %} method="post">
```

or in declaration:

```
def prd_btch_dtl(request):
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'm still struggling with some things, but this solution allowed me to render my report!